# Surface lying in the plane parallel to XY plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

find the area of the surface cut from the bottom of the paraboloid $x^2+y^2-z=0$ by the plane $4z=4$

my progress is.
$r(x,y)=x\hat i+y\hat j+f(x,y)$
      $$\frac{dr}{dx}=\hat i+0\hat j+2x\hat k$$
       $$\frac{dr}{dy}=0\hat i+\hat j+2y\hat k$$

$$\frac{dr}{dx}\times\frac{dr}{dy}=\hat i$$ got the answer as

converting into polar coordinates
$$A=\int\int\sqrt{4r^2}rdrd\,\theta$$

this is wat i got...is it right till here.

and also im sorry for the reading inconvinence ,'would u let me know..how do i pickup mathematical calculus symbols on this site...which could help me type and explain in better way.

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @user373605 Welcome to Maths SE.  __2__ things: I have reformatted your post but the input interpretation may be wrong so in future use
 [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $\LaTeX$ and secondly, 
if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut it on "belts", length of each belt is 2rπ where r=$\sqrt{z}$ and width is... see the image

[image]

$$\int_0^4 2\sqrt{z}\pi\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4z}}dz=4/3\pi(z+1/4)^{3/2}|_0^4=\frac{17^{3/2}-1}{6}\pi$$